# ng-class not rendering properly on Angular Condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have an html on which if I put 'color' in the input box, the paragraph must have red background. I think I am using ng-class properly, still not able to get it red. Can someone help?

***HTML:***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.red: {background:red}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p ng-class="{'red':entry=='color'}"> This is box. </p>
<input ng-model="entry" />
<script>
//Module Declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.entry = "";
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: ``red`` background  applies when ``entry`` value is ``color``, but in controller `$scope.entry`` is set to null.

Comment: Try after changing input content to color and then see; it does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in your CSS: there is a superfluous `:` after `.red`.

The correct declaration is:

```
.red {background:red}
```